# Haskell function composition question

Tags: haskell

If this works:

```
Prelude Data.Char> map toUpper ("sdfsd" ++ "dfgfdg")
"SDFSDDFGFDG"
```

Then why this doesn't?

```
Prelude Data.Char> map toUpper . (++) "sdfsd" "dfgfdg"

<interactive>:1:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `a -> [Char]'
           against inferred type `[Char]'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `(++) "sdfsd" "dfgfdg"'
    In the expression: map toUpper . (++) "sdfsd" "dfgfdg"
    In the definition of `it': it = map toUpper . (++) "sdfsd" "dfgfdg"
```

Comment: Operator precedence.  Function application "binds" very tightly; (.) binds very weakly.

Comment: `(.)` binds very tightly (precedence = 9), but function application binds even tighter (precedence = 10). Just insert `$` between the two strings to fix it. `$` has very low precedence, **0**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
map toUpper . (++) "sdfsd" "dfgfdg"
```

is parsed as:

```
(map toUpper) . ((++) "sdfsd" "dfgfdg")
```

So basically you're doing

```
(map toUpper) . "sdfsddfgfdg"
```

This does not work because the second argument to `.` needs to be a function, not a string.

I assume you were trying to do something more like `(map toUpper . (++)) "sdfsd" "dfgfdg"`. This also does not work because the return type of `++` is `[a] -> [a]` while the argument type of `map toUpper` is `[a]`.

The thing here is that while one might think of `++` as a function that takes two lists and returns a list, it really is a function that takes one list and then returns a function which takes another list and returns a list. To get what you want, you'd need to `++` into a function that takes a tuple of two lists and returns a list. That's called uncurrying. The following works:

```
map toUpper . (uncurry (++)) $ ("sdfsd", "dfgfdg")
```

Comment: Following your explanation, '(map toUpper . (++) "sdfsd") "dfgfdg"' should do the job. And it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You want `$` instead of `.` : `map toUpper $ (++) "sdfsd" "dfg"` works and does what you want. The reason for this is that `$` is a very low-precedence function application, so the corrected version reads as: "Apply the function `map toUpper` to the result of `(++) "sdfsd" "dfg"`".